# Typescript error using Angular "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"courses"' can't be used to index type 'Object'."

Tags: angular, typescript, database

I making a service in Angular to get all the courses from database, using the connection that was made using php. All doing well, but in process of doing my method to get the courses in a vector of type Curso, typescript return this error: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"course"' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
Property 'course' does not exist on type 'Object'." What am I missing? Line of error -> **this.vetor = res['course'];**

This is my class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Curso } from './curso';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CursoService {

  //URL
  url = "http://localhost/api/php/";

  //Vetor
  vetor: Curso[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //Getting all courses
  obterCursos():Observable<Curso[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.url+"list").pipe(
      map((res) => {
        this.vetor = res['course'];
        return this.vetor;
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to give `res` a type.

Comment: A simple `res: any` resolved my problem, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Set `res` to `any` type like that :

```
 map((res: any) => {
    this.vetor = res.course;
    return this.vetor;
  })
```